# applying "shaking" effect to image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have an image, and there is a button. 
When user taps the button, the image will have a shaking effect.

And the shaken image will be saved.

I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Please see this link, the normal image will be turned like the one on the left side ->   http://www.google.com.ph/imgres?q=shake+image+effect&um=1&hl=tl&safe=active&biw=957&bih=598&tbm=isch&tbnid=yZp_aN82rCfE4M:&imgrefurl=http://panasonic.net/avc/camcorder/hd/90_series/feature2.html&docid=tRDdMFUwGwMnEM&imgurl=http://panasonic.net/avc/camcorder/products/feature/hybrid_power_ois/01_hd_hybrid_90.jpg&w=460&h=160&ei=WZRdT87CEeSXiAKGvYCsCw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=550&vpy=159&dur=96&hovh=128&hovw=368&tx=297&ty=68&sig=109708826938815419817&page=3&tbnh=60&tbnw=173&start=35&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:35

Comment: do you mean, wiggle effect? like when you hold down an icon in home scren of iphone?

Comment: Sarah: i haven't done anything. I've seen tutorials but I don't want an animation.. I just want that the real image, will have a "blurred - shaking effect" as a post process. I don't know if this is also possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library can apply a motion blur effect to a UIImage:

https://github.com/gdawg/uiimage-dsp/tree/master/image-dsp

Comment: Thank you sir, what I was looking for is somehow related to this.

Answer (score 0):

is not very clear what you want to accomplish,

if you want to shake the image, an easy approach would be to use `animations` so you could change the frame of your image and make it bounce from frame to frame,

but I dont understand how this would change the image?

if you make a change in your image you can save it with

> IImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRepresentation functions

Check the
[UIIMage reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info

Comment: Sir, I'm looking for something like a "post process" that when the user taps the button, the real image will have a "shaking blurred effect".. Is that possible?